# Using collection_select for saving ID of two classes in a booking through has_many and belongs_to association throws error 'must exist' when saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many, belongs-to, collection-select

I am building a simple booking application for learning rails. I scaffolded people, cars and bookings.

Now when I try to create bookings I get

> 2 errors prohibited this booking from being saved:
>
> - Person must exist
> - Car must exist

### Code

`car.rb`

```rb
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bookings

  def brand_with_licence_plate
    "#{brand} #{licence_plate}"
  end

end
```

`person.rb`

```rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bookings

  def complete_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end

end
```

`bookings.rb`

```rb
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :Person
  belongs_to :Car
end
```

I added the columns for ID like so:

```rb
class AddItemsToBookings < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def self.up
    add_column :bookings, :car_id, :integer
    add_column :bookings, :person_id, :integer
  end
end
```

I added to following to `_form.html.erb`

```rb
 <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :Person %>
    <%= form.collection_select(:person_id, Person.all, :id, :complete_name) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :Car %>
    <%= form.select :car_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Car.all, 'id','brand_with_licence_plate') %>
  </div>
```

and added to `bookings_controller.rb`

```rb
def booking_params
      params.require(:booking).permit(:start, :end, :person_id, :car_id)
end
```

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412377/connecting-two-models-belongs-to-has-many-and-selecting-via-dropdown-in-form) and tried to change to `<%= form.select :car_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Car.all, 'id', 'brand_with_licence_plate') %>` as stated in one answer, but giving me the same error.

When I look at the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes) everything seems to be fine as well.

It seems as if am missing something fundamental here. Any ideas how to fix this are appreciated.

---

### Update:

I deleted the integer id column and run a new migration

```rb
class AddReferencesToBookingForPersonAndCar < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_reference :bookings, :people, foreign_key: true
    add_reference :bookings, :cars, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

and adjusted the permissions for params as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code doesn't look ok to me. I would change it like:

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :car
end
```

Mainly, person and car are lower case. Also, I noticed that in your migration you create cars, in plural. It should be:

```
class AddReferencesToBookingForPersonAndCar < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_reference :bookings, :person, foreign_key: true
    add_reference :bookings, :car, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

belongs_to :car expects a car_id and it looks like that the migration is creating a cars_id instead.

It would be easier to provide more help if you post the full controller code.

Comment: It seems that you want to link cars and people through booking. If that is correct, the has_many relations are incorrect. See many to many through on rails guides.

Comment: Thank it works like you suggested, only that I had to change people to singular as well.